# How to get list of tokens available in Polygon network using smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, external-api, polygon

I want to get the names of all the tokens which are available in Polygon using a smart contract(solidity), how can I achieve that?

Comment: Is using an offchain part acceptable ? You might have to send new token to your sc, via a bot for instance

Answer (score -1):

Ok i think dextools page showing whenever a new token liquidity added in polygon dexes, it automatically popping up. Link: https://www.dextools.io/app/polygon/pool-explorer

Comment: This is offchain while OP asks for data "using a smartcontract"